# Can't invite a new user to the organisation despite being an organisation manager

Tags: ibm-cloud

According to the Bluemix docs https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/users_roles.html#userrolesinfo the Organisation Manager role can:

"...create, view, edit, or delete spaces within the organization, view the organization's usage and quota, **invite team members to the organization**, manage who has access to the organization and their roles in the organization, and manage custom domains for the organization."

It also says "Account owners and organization managers can invite team members to orgs from the Invite Team Members page."

I'm not the Owner of the organisation but I am a Manager of the organisation:

[image: Org permissions dialog]

So, according to the docs, I should be able to see the Invite User button, but I can't. Is this a bug?

[image: Space permissions dialog]

The description in the docs makes more sense than the current behaviour. I've been made an organisation manager so that the account owner can share the workload and so that he has a back-up in case he gets hit by a bus. It would be frustrating for him to have to go through and do all the inviting for spaces in our organisation.

Thanks,

Laura

Answer (score 1):

Laura,

Not a bug, it's a context thing.  Check the menu bar on the left.  In order to invite someone to your **Organization**, you need to have the Organization highlighted on the left hand nav bar.  Then you will see a screen that looks like this, with the link to invite a new user:[image: Organization properties]

Once the person has been invited to the **Organization**, I can then add them to specific **spaces** within the organization.  So now go and highlight one of the spaces under your organization.  You will see a screen like this:
[image: Space properties]

At this point you should see your newly invited user in the pulldown menu, and you should be able to give them access to a particular space within your organization.

Comment: Yes, I had the organisation selected but still nothing. However, when I switch to New Bluemix view/theme, I get an 'Invite Team Members' option which seems to let me add people.

Answer (score 0):

Laura, to invite users you need to be a member of the organization and not collaborator. Can you please confirm if you are a member to the organization in question ? if not you will not be able to invite users even if you have the privilege of manager. Hope this helps.

Comment: I assume I'm a member. I don't know how I'd tell if I was only a collaborator. Anyway, bizarrely, in the Classic Bluemix view, I didn't get an Invite Members option at all. But when I switch to New Bluemix view, I can Invite Team Members. So I'm guessing I'm a member.